# Column A contains divagar1,column B contains siva1 for 500 rows and i need Column C Value to be divagar1.siva@gmail.com

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I need column c value to divagar1.siva1@gmail.com for Column c. And for the next row to be divagar2.siva2@gmail.com and for the corresponding rows

Comment: How much have you researched really?

Comment: If you haven't at all, try googling Text manipulation in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=A1&"."&B1&"@gmail.com"
```

Then drag down.

Another version:

```
=CONCATENATE(A1,".",B1,"@gmail.com")
```